# Javascript event addEventListener registering multiple times for same function; using OOP Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, events, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm employing Object-Oriented Javascript, in conjunction with registering event listeners. From what I understand about event listeners, if the function applied to eventtarget has already been registered, repeated attempts to add this same event listener will be ignored. In other words, it should only fire once. But that is not the case in the code below (also can be seen on jsfiddle).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

> Multiple identical event listeners
>
> If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are discarded. They do not cause the EventListener to be called twice, and since the duplicates are discarded, they do not need to be removed manually with the removeEventListener method.

http://jsfiddle.net/qd1e8f6c/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input id="t1" type="text" />
    <input id="btn" type="button" />
</div>
```

JS

```
var namespace = namespace || {};

namespace.event = {
    addListener: function(el, type) {
        var handle = function() {
            switch (type) {
                case "focus": 
                    console.log(el.value);
                    break;
                case "click":
                    console.log(el.id + " was clicked");
                    break;
            }
        };
        
        el.addEventListener(type, handle, false);
    }
};

namespace.ExampleClass = function() {
    this.init = function(el1, el2) {
        el1.value = "123";
        el2.value = "Click Me";
    };
};

var textbox = document.getElementById("t1");
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
    
var inst = new namespace.ExampleClass();
    
inst.init( textbox, button );
    
namespace.event.addListener(textbox, "focus");
namespace.event.addListener(button, "click");

// same handle -- shoudln't it only add the event once?
namespace.event.addListener(textbox, "focus");
namespace.event.addListener(button, "click");
```

As you can see in the last few lines of the code above, a function called `addListener` is executed twice, which registers an event to each input. Then, `addListener` is executed again. I'm expecting it to not register again and ignore, but it actually registers. I don't get it. The function in the namespace called `handle` is exactly the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Any help would be great.

Comment: you didn't do anything to prevent it from adding the event twice, not sure why you would expect it to do that automatically.

Comment: Because I was under the impression that it the addEventListener does not register the event again if the target is the same and the handle is the same.

Comment: I just pasted a quote from the mozilla link on the addEventListener. Unless I'm reading it incorrectly, and I may be, I'm interpreting it as the event will only fire once.

Comment: Sorry, yes of course. @loganfsmyth explains it.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot bind the same type/function pair to an element. However, that is not what you are doing, you are explicitly creating a new `handler` function on every call to your `namespace.addEventListener` function.

What you have:

```
namespace.event = {
    addListener: function(el, type) {
        var handle = function() {
            switch (type) {
                case "focus": 
                    console.log(el.value);
                    break;
                case "click":
                    console.log(el.id + " was clicked");
                    break;
            }
        };

        el.addEventListener(type, handle, false);
    }
};
```

What would do what you expect:

```
var handle = function(evt) {
    var el = evt.currentTarget;

    switch (type) {
        case "focus": 
            console.log(el.value);
            break;
        case "click":
            console.log(el.id + " was clicked");
            break;
    }
};

namespace.event = {
    addListener: function(el, type) {
        el.addEventListener(type, handle, false);
    }
};
```

because there is only one instance of `handle` in the second case.

#### Namespacing

What you have is one approach to namespacing, but most often these days, JS namespacing is done via the [Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

For your case for example, you don't even appear to really care about making your code globally accessible via this 'namespace' variable since it is only used in your code, so you could do:

```
var namespace = (function(){
    function handle(evt) {
        var el = evt.currentTarget;

        switch (type) {
            case "focus": 
                console.log(el.value);
                break;
            case "click":
                console.log(el.id + " was clicked");
               break;
        }
    };

    function addListener(el, type) {
        el.addEventListener(type, handle, false);
    }

    function ExampleClass() {
        this.init = function(el1, el2) {
            el1.value = "123";
            el2.value = "Click Me";
        };
    };

    var textbox = document.getElementById("t1");
    var button = document.getElementById("btn");

    var inst = new ExampleClass();

    inst.init( textbox, button );

    addListener(textbox, "focus");
    addListener(button, "click");


    // And if you do care about 'inst' being global, you'd explicitly add it to the window.
    window.inst = inst;

    // Whatever functions you want to expose as 'namespace' would go here.
    return {
        event: {
            addEventListener: addEventListener
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example! I appreciate it very much. Question? If I made the `handle` function a subset of `namespace`, would addEventListener fire only once? I want to keep function declarations inside `namespace`, if at all possible. Thanks again.

Comment: That would be fine, since there is still one instance of the function. Can I ask why these all need to live on the namespace though? That's an ugly way to do it and there may be better approaches.

Comment: Sure, you may. I'm modifying a few functions of a vendor's program for a fix (the vendor did not provide a fix so I'm the messenger to fix it). These vendor functions may be called repeatedly in the same session. Therefore, I need to ensure events are only registered once. I don't want to affect their myriad JS files; so, I put everything inside my own namespace. If there is a better approach, I would love to hear it. This was the best approach I could think of, without conflicting with the vendor's code.

Comment: Oh, Wow. Thank you so much for that education. I'll definitely read up on the link and try to implement this. Thanks, once more!

Comment: Hi. I don't know how to move to this to a discussion but there is one correction. I actually do want my code accessible globally. I create the namespace and class in my own JS file. Then I reference the JS file in the vendor's program. And I modify a handful of the vendor's JS functions, in conjunction with the namespace and class I created. I don't know if i can still use closures in the way the link discusses but I'll definitely experiment. Thank you.

Comment: @user3907208 Tweaked my example. Basically you'd return an object with whatever you want to publicly expose.